# Syntax error in if-else statement

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am using the following piece of code in Python 3.6:

```
age = 65
 retirement = age - 64
 if retirement < 10:
  print "(you will get retire soon)"
  else:
  Syntax Error: invalid syntax
```

I tried several different ways in an if-else statement but it still does not work.

Does anyone know a way for the program to detect the errors for me? Thanks.

Comment: The `if` and the `else` are not vertically aligned. The `else` block has no statements. Everything but the first line is for some reason indented.

Comment: Fix this `print "(you will get retire soon)"` to this `print("you will get retire soon")` and fix your code indentation as well.

Comment: python is indentation sensitive... https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html

Comment: Hey it still isn't working  here is my code :

Comment: age = 65
>>> retirement = 65 - 1
>>> if retirement < 1:
 print ("okay")
 else:  Syntax Error

Comment: so you mean i have to add else block statement but why i saw many code self taught learning they don't have it

Comment: it stills not work

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that you're (probably) looking for, but you should use the help of a python tutorial:

```
age = 65
retirement = age - 64
if retirement < 10:
    print("you will get retire soon")
else:
    raise SyntaxError
```

i also don't get why you want to raise a SyntaxError... Maybe a ValueError is better, and the best should be:

```
age = 65
retirement = age - 64
if retirement < 10:
    print("you will get retire soon")
else:
    print("still long suffering")
```

Comment: the print statement, in python3.x, use parenthesis. I've edited the code, have a look now (and remember that for some reasons you're raising a SyntaxError if retirement >= 10 in the first example, use the second example to avoid that)

Comment: i used parenthesis abut why i type else: it showed out SyntaxErrors : invalid syntax

Comment: The `else` condition is strictly correlated to the `if` condition. for better understand what is going on, use the second example or eliminate the `else` line and everything under that

Comment: It is any problem if i use shell to type that